# google oauth screen doesn't show up

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

so I am learning google OAuth, and I wrote this:

```
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bp = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(session({
  secret: "Our little secret.",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true  });
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/auth/google", function(req, res){
  passport.authenticate(("google", { scope: ["profile"] }), function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/login");
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("secrets");
  }else{
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});


app.post("/register", function(req, res){
  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      res.redirect("register");
    }else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });
});


app.post("/login", function(req, res){
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

but when I try to register with google the authentication screen does not show up, I created the app on the google developers console and they were saying this:

> "Your app will only be accessible to people on your test user list. Once your app is ready for publishing, you may need to validate it."

don't know what to do, it's my first time with Google OAuth.

Comment: Did you add yourself to the test user list as the message says? Are you still unable to see the OAuth consent screen even after you've added users to the test user list for your app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to google developer console under consent screen you will find

[image]

While your application has not been verified you can add additional users here these are your developers who will be able to access your application while it is still in development.

I have a video which walks you through how to add the users. [Google OAuth Error 403: access_denied easy fix.](https://youtu.be/x_NPvk0pk8g)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helps,it will always increase your reputation